# Algebraic manipulation on removing common factor outside

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

d[i,j] and M[i,j] are elements of size arrays of size 2x2

After some manipulations I get this as Output

```
  I d[1, 2] d[2, 1] M[1, 2]   I d[1, 1] d[2, 2] M[1, 2]
---------------------------- - ------------------------- + 
      det (Iw + M)                det (Iw + M)

  I d[1, 1] d[2, 2] M[2, 1]   I d[1, 2] d[2, 1] M[2, 1]
  ------------------------- - -------------------------
        det (Iw + M)                det (Iw + M)
```

So I did **Collect[]** to collect M[1,2] and M[2,1]

```
Collect[(I*d[1, 2]*d[2, 1]*M[1, 2])/(det*(Iw + M)) - 
   (I*d[1, 1]*d[2, 2]*M[1, 2])/(det*(Iw + M)) - 
   (I*d[1, 2]*d[2, 1]*M[2, 1])/(det*(Iw + M)) + 
   (I*d[1, 1]*d[2, 2]*M[2, 1])/(det*(Iw + M)), {M[1, 2], M[2, 1]}]
```

and I get the output as

```
 I d[1, 2] d[2, 1]   I d[1, 1] d[2, 2]
(----------------- - -----------------) M[1, 2] + 
   det (Iw + M)        det (Iw + M)

     I d[1, 2] d[2, 1]    I d[1, 1] d[2, 2]
  (-(-----------------) + -----------------) M[2, 1]
       det (Iw + M)         det (Iw + M)
```

Now I want to remove particular common **I** out  of the numerator brackets and also make the terms to add up.

Please let me know how to do

Comment: `Simplify[Collect[(I*d[1,2]*...]/I]` removes all the `I` from your expression. In other words just divide your expression by `I` and then `Simplify`

Comment: How do I add up the terms in the brackets ?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean "add up the terms in brackets". `d[1,2]` tells Mathematica that d is a function of 2 arguments. Do you want to change `d[1, 2]` into 3 and `d[2,2]` into 4? Perhaps edit your post showing what you want the result to be

Comment: @Bill it's pretty clear that OP meant `d[[1,2]]`

Comment: does `Factor@Collect[(I*d[1, 2]*d[2, 1]*M[1, 2])/(det*(Iw + M)) - (I*
      d[1, 1]*d[2, 2]*M[1, 2])/(det*(Iw + M)) - (I*d[1, 2]*d[2, 1]*
      M[2, 1])/(det*(Iw + M)) + (I*d[1, 1]*d[2, 2]*
      M[2, 1])/(det*(Iw + M)), {M[1, 2], M[2, 1]}]` give what you need?